# How to Cast parent class object to child class object?

Tags: java

**Class A**

package com.test.test;

```
public class A {

  public void printA(){
    System.out.println("A");
  }

}
```

**Class B**

```
package com.test.test;

    public class B extends A {

      public void print(){
        System.out.println("B");
      }

    }
```

**Class C**

```
 package com.test.test;

    public class C {

      public static void main(String[] args) {


        B b = (B) new A();

         b.printA();
         b.print();
      }

    }
```

Getting below exception

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.test.test.A cannot be cast to com.test.test.B     at
>   com.test.test.C.main(C.java:8)

Comment: it's not possible to convert an `A` object to a `B` object

Comment: @AndyTurner right reason, wrong language

Comment: think about it - how does your `new A()` suddenly acquire the methods _and fields_ of a `B` simply by casting it to a `B` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to Convert parent class object to child class object?

In your code, you aren't *converting* anything, you're casting. *Casting* (the thing you're doing with `(B)`) just changes the kind of reference you have to an object, it doesn't change the *object* at all. If the new reference type isn't supported by the object, the cast fails (as you've discovered).

You can't *convert* an object, but you can create a new object based on another object. It would be possible, for instance, to define a `B` constructor that accepted an `A` instance and used information from it as part of the process of initializing a `B` instance.

Answer (score 0):

Java **does not allow** the conversion of Parent class to Child class.
So you are getting the exception.

It is due to the simple rule the Child class is the subclass of the Parent class, i.e. it inherits from the Parent class.
So you can never perform such a conversion.

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to convert parent to child as the child is enhanced from the parent and getting the parent to get the child enhancements is not possible.

Comment: @Alnitak enhanced answer